# zend_Http_Client doesn't connect when uploaded to web server

Tags: zend-framework

my zend app is working fine on my local server but when i upload all the file to my main webserver, the following code throws this error:

> #### Exception information:
>
> **Message:** Unable to Connect to tcp://stage.mydomain.com:80. Error #0: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not

i'm using an this zend function:

```
 $this->_http = new Zend_Http_Client();
    $this->_http->setUri('http://staging.mydomain.com/jserver');
    $this->_http->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
    $this->_http->setRawData(json_encode($this->_apirequest));
    echo $this->_http->request()->getBody();
```

this works on my local when i change the URI to my.local/jserver

oh yeh, maybe this could be the problem...   to access the staging.mydomain.com  i have to change my hosts file for windows..  so the browser redirects to that ip.

not sure.

Comment: you can :) try `hosts` and `known_hosts`(if exist) files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right. remote  server knows nothing about your hosts file. try to use ip, not the domain name

Comment: ok, knew it.. but cant i add the line into the server hosts file. i found one in etc/hosts ?